# How to send Monit alerts with MSMTP?

Tags: debian, monit, msmtp

I've got a Debian 11 system running as a local file server. I want to keep it as simple as possible but have some basic monitoring from Monit. I've installed and configured `msmtp` and `msmtp-mta` and I've confirmed that I can send test messages from the command line with

```
mail -s "test" address@email.com <<END
This is a test
END
```

and I've got emails coming through from `unattended-upgrades`.

I've seen guides where SMTP details are entered in the Monit config files, but I would prefer to only have the details stored in one place (`/etc/msmtprc`), so in my monit config file I've put `set mailserver localhost`. Monit is trying and failing to connect - in `/var/log/monit.log` I see:

```
[2023-04-25T16:43:24+0100] error    : Cannot connect to [localhost]:25 -- Connection refused
[2023-04-25T16:43:24+0100] error    : Cannot open a connection to the mailserver localhost:25 -- Operation now in progress
[2023-04-25T16:43:24+0100] error    : Mail: Delivery failed -- no mail server is available
```

Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: It appears the MTA daemon component of msmtp is not running (yet). A succesful  mail command is not a test to check the daemon  (`mail` makes use of the `/usr/lib/sendmail` function rather than connecting to port 25)  https://marlam.de/msmtp/msmtp.html#Minimal-SMTP-server-_0028msmtpd_0029

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @HBruijn, I thought it was something like that - the daemon was installed but not running.

I found [a guide](https://janvrany.github.io/2022/02/how-to-set-up-msmtpd.html) on how to set this up manually, but then I realised that the Debian package comes with an `msmtpd.service` file already (which was disabled), so I simply needed to run
`systemctl enable msmtpd.service` and
`systemctl start msmtpd.service`.

I then hit a permissions issue, which is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1289573/msmtp-sendmail-account-default-not-found-no-configuration-file-available-sys) - I ran
`chgrp msmtp /etc/msmtprc` and
`chmod g+r /etc/msmtprc` to allow the process to read the config file, and now it's working.